# Find next lowest value over partition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I'm looking for a one-liner window function to get the next lowest value of Field2 over a partition of Field1 without a subquery.

```
Field1   Field2      Last_Val
A         1          Null
A         2          1
A         2          1
A         2          1
A         3          2
B         1          Null
B         7          1
```

I know how to do it a few ways, easiest being

```
  SELECT T1.Field1,
         T1.Field2,
         ( SELECT MAX(T2.Field2)
             FROM TEST_DATA T2
            WHERE T1.Field1 = T2.Field1
              AND T1.Field2 > T2.Field2
         ) last_val
    FROM TEST_DATA T1;
```

But I'm interested if it can be done in a single clause.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with a single function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your values are integers, then this works:

```
with t as (
      select 'A' as field1, 1 as field2 from dual union all
      select 'A', 2 from dual union all
      select 'A', 2 from dual union all
      select 'A', 2 from dual union all
      select 'A', 3 from dual
     )
select t.*,
        max(field2) over (partition by field1 order by field2 range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
from t;
```

Comment: Good caveat about integers, though you could handle _most_ non-integer values by using something like `power(10,-84) PRECEDING` instead of `1 PRECEDING`.

Answer (score 2):

You need a windowed analytic function with the `RANGE` clause:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Field1, Field2 ) AS
SELECT 'A', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 7 FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
select field1,
       field2,
       max(field2) over(
         partition by field1
         order by field2
         range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
       ) as last_val
from   table_name
```

**Output**:

> ```
> FIELD1 | FIELD2 | LAST_VAL
> :----- | -----: | -------:
> A      |      1 |     null
> A      |      2 |        1
> A      |      2 |        1
> A      |      2 |        1
> A      |      3 |        2
> B      |      1 |     null
> B      |      7 |        1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fc96949399087ab68689c832e4e8ffe9)*