# How can i bring a previous value over a group using lag?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-05 |
| 2 | 2023-10-05 |
| 3 | 2023-10-05 |
| 4 | 2023-10-05 |
| 1 | 2023-10-10 |
| 2 | 2023-10-10 |
| 3 | 2023-10-10 |
| 4 | 2023-10-10 |

What i'd like to see is

| ID | Date | Previous Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-05 | null |
| 2 | 2023-10-05 | null |
| 3 | 2023-10-05 | null |
| 4 | 2023-10-05 | null |
| 1 | 2023-10-10 | 2023-10-05 |
| 2 | 2023-10-10 | 2023-10-05 |
| 3 | 2023-10-10 | 2023-10-05 |
| 4 | 2023-10-10 | 2023-10-05 |

This is what I've tried:

```
select ID, Date, lag(Date) over (partition by Date order by Date)
from Table;
```

But the result just shows the date of the preceeding row, not the preceeding group (indicated in the PARTITION BY portion), so i get this result:

| ID | Date | Previous Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-05 | null |
| 2 | 2023-10-05 | 2023-10-05 |
| 3 | 2023-10-05 | 2023-10-05 |
| 4 | 2023-10-05 | 2023-10-05 |
| 1 | 2023-10-10 | 2023-10-05 |
| 2 | 2023-10-10 | 2023-10-10 |
| 3 | 2023-10-10 | 2023-10-10 |
| 4 | 2023-10-10 | 2023-10-10 |

How can I show the previous date by group ignoring ID in the same query without the need of subqueries or joins using SQL?

***EDIT*** *********

I tried @The Impaler's answer below, it is working and bringing the correct values for most of the rows, however this is where it's failing:

Let's say we have ID from 1 to 4 for date 2023-10-05, and then for the next date 2023-10-10 we have ID from 1 to 6, so the partition by ID will only work if ID values repeat between month, but not for new IDs in that month not present in the previous month:

| ID | Date | Previous Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-05 | null |
| 2 | 2023-10-05 | null |
| 3 | 2023-10-05 | null |
| 4 | 2023-10-05 | null |
| 1 | 2023-10-10 | 2023-10-05 |
| 2 | 2023-10-10 | 2023-10-05 |
| 3 | 2023-10-10 | 2023-10-05 |
| 4 | 2023-10-10 | 2023-10-05 |
| 5 | 2023-10-10 | null |
| 6 | 2023-10-10 | null |

Thanks

Comment: I had a similar question awhile back. The boneheaded approach in my question body will work for I think most any DBMS. The answers are clever and avoid additional joins, but use less universal functions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56992735/find-next-lowest-value-over-partition

Comment: Thanks @Error_2646 i will take a look into it

Comment: @Error_2646 i tried the approach but at least in spark LAG function doesn't allow to specify the window (it does error out)

Comment: In the new sample result from the edit, ids 5 & 6 should have 2023-10-05, correct? The data in the edit is the current work in progress result?

Comment: @Error_2646 that's correct, yes, the data in the edit is the work in progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the apache documentation it seems this is supported by the base dialect. I use a platform built on spark with additional bells and whistles so not 100% sure.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-window.html

last_distinct_date_value gives how I'm interpreting the question.

last_date_by_id is the existing answer for comparison.

```
with some_sample_data as (
SELECT data.id, _date
    FROM VALUES (1, cast('2023-10-05' as date)),
                (2, cast('2023-10-05' as date)),
                (3, cast('2023-10-05' as date)),
                (4, cast('2023-10-05' as date)),
                (1, cast('2023-10-09' as date)),
                (1, cast('2023-10-10' as date)),
                (2, cast('2023-10-10' as date)),
                (3, cast('2023-10-10' as date)),
                (4, cast('2023-10-10' as date)),
                (5, cast('2023-10-10' as date)),
                (6, cast('2023-10-10' as date)),
                (7, cast('2023-10-15' as date))
                 AS data(id, _date)
)
select id,
       _date,
       max(_date) over(
         partition by 1
             order by _date
         range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
       ) as last_distinct_date_value,
       lag(_date) over(
         partition by id
             order by _date
       ) as last_date_by_id
  from some_sample_data



id  _date       last_distinct_date_value    last_date_by_id
1   2023-10-05  -                           -
2   2023-10-05  -                           -
3   2023-10-05  -                           -
4   2023-10-05  -                           -
1   2023-10-09  2023-10-05                  2023-10-05
1   2023-10-10  2023-10-09                  2023-10-09
2   2023-10-10  2023-10-09                  2023-10-05
3   2023-10-10  2023-10-09                  2023-10-05
4   2023-10-10  2023-10-09                  2023-10-05
5   2023-10-10  2023-10-09                  -
6   2023-10-10  2023-10-09                  -
7   2023-10-15  2023-10-10                  -
```

Comment: whoa, hats off mate! working as requested!Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but your partition is incorrect. The following query should produce the result you want:

```sql
select ID, Date,
  lag(Date) over (partition by id order by Date) as previous_date
from Table
order by date, id
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! 7 more minutes need to pass before I can accept it

Comment: @JoseR Be careful this is actually what you want. This answer is good and it makes total sense if your grouping is by id. But I read your question a bit different. That you wanted to ignore the ids and consider date groupings, say you insert a record with ID: 1 and Date: 2023-10-09. With this all your 2023-10-10 records will stay 2023-10-05 except for ID:1. Which could be totally valid.

Comment: Yep, seems i was a little bit hasty, this is working for most of the rows, but for some rows it is leaving them out as null

Comment: I fail to understand the special case. @JoseR Can you update the question to include it, so I can see i better?

Comment: Sure, let me update the question

Comment: @TheImpaler the issue is for new IDs in that month not present in the previous one.  See updated question.  Thanks

Comment: @JoseR I tested the query in a PostgreSQL [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gzXoM5M4) (don't have access to a Spark fiddle) and it seems it works as expected. Is this what you need?

Comment: Hi @TheImpaler thanks, not entirely, the last two rows also should show the previous month even if they didn't exist in that previous month

Comment: I see you need all the IDs in all the dates. If that's the case, then you need a `cross join` to **make up** all the combinations, even the non-existent ones. Then the lag() function will produce the correct data. I think you don't want joins in the answer, though.

Comment: On second thought this also will help me, as I need to count the newly created IDs vs the previous months so them showing as null will help with that.